# Importance of power series in calculus.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I know that power series such as Taylor and Maclaurin series are significantly important in calculus in terms of approxiations, but I was wondering if there's more than just that. What is the importance of power series in calculus?

Comment: You can solve some differential equation with power series developpement !

Comment: Evaluating infinite series!

Comment: Power series are especially important in complex analysis.

Comment: @Mark why in complex analysis?

Comment: @Syn1110 All complex differentiable functions (which are the "interesting" functions) can be locally represented as power series. This leads to many nice results-for example, you can prove that a complex differentiable function is differentiable infinitely many times. (which is obviously false in real analysis)